# Is it possible to create a laser in the extremely low frequency radio spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser, radiation, technology

I have been reading about effort to push lasers into the hard X-Ray and soft Gamma Ray range, been quoted as one of the most important problems in physics according to Vitaly Ginzburg.
However, would a coherent light wave in the opposite side of the spectrum be feasible or more challenging than one with such high frequency?

Comment: Masers came before lasers. Define extremely low frequency - Hz, kHz, MHz, ...?

Answer (score 3):

It’s not easy, and it’s also not necessary. Powerful, relatively inexpensive amplifiers exist for radio-frequency (and lower) radiation. And by phased arrays, you can get directed “beams.” Also, it’s all coherent! The power of electronics takes over, and so going through the trouble of building a RF laser is a pointless endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on a laser, [a free electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser) can in principle implement a low-frequency beam if you make it long enough to accommodate the wavelength. Normally they can go down to millimeter wavelengths, but at least in principle one could scale things up.